# When to implement soft delete logic in the code over the database?

Tags: database, soft-delete

When I want to soft delete resources as a policy of my company I can do it in one of two places.

I can do it in my database with some "instead of DELETE" trigger. Like so:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER prevent_resource_delete
    BEFORE DELETE ON resource
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE resource_soft_delete();

CREATE FUNCTION resource_soft_delete() RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE resource SET deleted_at = now() WHERE id = OLD.id;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$;
```

That's how pretty much every article about soft deletes suggests to do it. Other than articles written specifically by a ORM owner because they have their in-house solution.

I like this approach. The logic in my APIs looks like I am just deleting the resource.

```js
Resource.query().deleteById(id); // Using a query builder
db.query('DELETE FROM resource WHERE id = $1;', [id]); // Using native library
```

To me it seems more natural and I don't have to worry about other developers accidentally hard deleting stuff. But it can also be confusing to those who don't know what is actually going on. And having any logic in the database means I can have bugs there (soft deleting logic is usually dead simple, but still...), which would be hard to debug. At least compared to those in my APIs.

But also I can instead have the logic in the APIs themselves. Keeping logic next to the other logic. Less elegant but more straightforward. No hidden logic somewhere else. I do lose the protection from people accidentally hard deleting resources.

```js
Resource.query().findById(id).patch({deleted_at: new Date()}); // Using a query builder
db.query('UPDATE resource SET deleted_at = now() WHERE id = $1;', [id]); // Using native library
```

I am inclined to choose the former option as I consider the choice of whether to soft delete a database matter. The database chooses what to do with deleted data. Deleted data, soft or hard, is in principle not part of the application anymore. The APIs can't retrieve it. It is for me, the developer, to use for analytics, legal reasons or to manually aid a user who wants to recover something he/she considers lost.

But I don't like the downsides. I just talked to a colleague that was worried because he thought we were actually deleting stuff. Now, that could actually be solved with better onboarding and documentation. But should it be like that?

When to implement soft delete logic in the code over the database? Why does every article I find directly suggest the database without even considering the code? It looks like there is a strong reason I can't find.

Answer (score 0):

As per me there isn't any strong reason, it depends on the architect and developer where they decide to put the logic, but below could be the possible reasons behind it ::

First is, as we are deleting something from the DB, so keeping the logic where it's best suited and,

Second writing the logic for each and every API is kind of redundant instead doing it in DB once and for all tables or nodes or collections is of less work to do. :)